# Apply updates automatically when available

Tags: updates, auto-updates

Is it possible to automatically apply Craft CMS updates when they become available?

At the moment, I have to go into the CPanel and apply updates with the one-click option.

Maybe I can do this with a cron job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can, but it's going to be a little bit tricky since you have to be logged in or you have to find a way how to login with an automatic request.
Like others said, it's a dangerous things and I would not suggest to auto update since something can eventually break and you'll not notice it before your customers.

What you can do is

1. Create a controller that uses the `user` service to login with admin credentials
2. Redirect to `admin/updates/go/craft` <- this will start the update

Making an update for Craft 2 is actually just visiting the `admin/updates/go/craft` everything else is automatic

Comment: I agree with you both that it's bad practice. I want to experiment with this within a staging environment :)

Comment: Alright, if it's only for staging servers it might be ok. If you are not able to create an auto login I can provide one. I'm currently on my smartphone so it's a little bit tricky to write code but it requires actually all in all only about 10-15 lines because craft has many ready to use functions for that

Answer (score 2):

It's typically bad practice to allow auto-updates -- at least in a production environment.

That being said, to update Craft, you're required to download the new files (click "Download" on the update page and it gives you a zip file), and then replace them in your codebase. So right now, no you wouldn't be able to do this with a Cron Job.

Craft 3 may be a different story, though.